# Что лучше использовать if vs Switch?

Tags: php, оптимизация

Добрый вечер. Всегда было интересно что лучше использовать переключатель switch или оператор if для множества условий, в частности для каждого переборки условий. Но как это по оптимизации, как бы чтобы реализовать switch надо больше программного кода, чем для if. Кто проводил тесты подскажите пожалуйста.

Comment: При выполнении скрипта все if становятся switch, поэтому switch быстрее. Нужно использовать то что логичнее. Для сравнения: if. А для выбора из списка: switch

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[If vs. Switch Speed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/445067/if-vs-switch-speed).

По самому простому, свитч быстрее потому что эту не надо нечего решать - пришло значение - переключился на него - выполнил действие, в случае ифа - надо что-то с чем-то сравнить... =) (такое козырное объяснение на пальцах - для тех, кто будет говорить, что там только для шарпа, а в пхп все по другому =) )

Comment: Если не прав - поправьте, но:

    switch( condition ) {
     case someValue:
     // как вы думаете что здесь происходит?
     // именно сравнение condition с someValue и происходит
     break;
    }

Comment: я немного не правильно сформировал идею. по правилам в someValue - должны быть константные значение, что позволит компилятору сделать хэш-меп, и по приходу значения - сразу найти, за константное время, и выполнить действие, в случае с if - значение буду сравниваться дольше.

Comment: @Gorets - я понимаю о чем вы, просто я сильно сомневаюсь что PHP интерпретатор это делает ( В первую очередь вопрос о PHP. Не утверждаю, возможно я не прав ).

На самом деле, когда switch небольшой, его, практически всегда, можно избежать, либо сделать что-то типа того, о чем писал я.

А если switch большой, значит вы **определенно** что-то делаете не так :)

Answer (score 6):

На мой взгляд, в подавляющем большинстве ситуаций, лучше вообще не использовать ни switch, ни много if'ов.

Грубо говоря вместо:

```
switch( state ) {
  case(0):

  break;
  case(1):

  break;
  case(2):

  break;
  case(N):

  break;
  default: ...
}
```

На мой взгляд, когда это возможно ( а возможно это, скорее всего, всегда т.к. я уже наверное больше года не использовал switch :) ), лучше писать что-то типа

```
// PHP 5.3+ использую анонимные функции
$cases = array(
 function() {

 },
 function() {

 },
 // ...
);
if( !empty( $cases[$state] ) ) {
   $handler = $cases[$state];
   $handler();
}
else {
   // default
}

// аналогично JS
var cases = [function(){},function(){},...];
if( cases[ state ] ) {
  cases[ state ]();
}
else {
  // default
}
```

На мой взгляд, такой подход, в первую очередь, более гибкий в плане возможных будущих изменений и, что немаловажно, непосредственно, читабельности.

К тому-же я эстетически неперевариваю ни 100500 if, else if блоков, но switch. Довольно часто, когда кто-то начинает писать логику вида `if else if` - он не может остановиться, в конечном счете код превращается в нечитабельное месиво. Но у `if else`, на самом деле, другое применение. Некоторые программисты сознательно используют такую конструкцию вместо `switch`. И я их понимаю, на мой взгляд синтаксис switch просто отвратителен ( независимо от языка, хотя, возможно, где-то он реализован красивее, но я таких не знаю да и речь сейчас не о них )

Если же речь о производительности, то это 100% не то, что нужно оптимизировать, с большим трудом себе представляю PHP код, который проседает на `if else if` or `switch`.

Справедливости ради - switch может хорошо оптимизироваться компилятором, но для PHP это не актуально :)

---

В примерах я рассматривал целочисленные cas'ы, но, я думаю, что и так понятно, что для строковых cas'ов просто напросто используются ассоциативный массив в PHP и Object hash нотация в JavaScript. Т.е. все что измениться, это непосредственно объявление cas'ов, остальная логика не меняется.

---

*UPD*: каюсь, немного соврал. `switch` я таки использую и советую использовать при написании парсеров.

Comment: категорически несогласен. ко всему же, смотря на твой код - это вообще какой-то велосипед, смесь прозрачного в понимании switch с if, зашитым в массив вариантов действий... но если это общая пхп-практика - тогда пусть она такой и остается и такие методы дальше пхп не расходятся...

Comment: @Gorets - я на PHP уже очень давно не пишу, не переживай, не разойдется. Я не ору что-бы все так делали, лишь высказал свое мнение ( в контексте PHP это действительно что-то необычное, но в контексте JS распостраненная практика, которая, чисто к слову, может, в некоторых случаях дать значительный прирост производительности, по сравнению с `switch` )

Прозрачный в понимании `switch`? Возможно switch и прозрачен, но, лично я, не могу назвать его лаконичным. К тому-же, когда размер switcha достигает овер 100+ case'ов код становиться полным... ну вы понимаете о чем я

Comment: так я тоже высказываю сугубо личное мнение, и не на пхп и не на жс не пишу... ну и switch с больше, чем 10 значение(или if) - любому будет глаз резать.. в общем как и твой способ, представь var cases = [function(){},function(){},function(){},function(){},function(){},function(){},function(){},function(){},function(){},function(){},function(){},function(){},function(){},function(){},function(){},function(){},function(){},function(){},function(){},function(){},function(){},function(){},function(){},function(){},function(){},function(){},function(){},function(){},function(){},function(){},...];

Comment: @Gorets - вы смеетесь?

    var cases = [
      function() {
        // .....
      }, 
      function() {
        // .....
      },
      function() {
        // .....
      },
      // .....
    ]

Если у вас проблемы с пониманием того, как по нормальному форматировать код, то это не ко мне. К тому-же, про switch длиною в овер 100500 case'ов я уже писал.

К тому-же про swtch длиной ов

Answer (score 5):

> @Gorets - пришло значение - переключился на него - выполнил действие

Это удивительно. Каким образом switch переключается?
И отвечая на данный вопрос обратимся к мане http://php.net/manual/ru/control-structures.switch.php и находим:
Замечание:

> Заметьте, что конструкция switch/case использует неточное сравнение (==).
>   то есть делает сверку "так же" как и IF.
>   Разница в скорости есть но она явно не обусловлена "магическим переключением" если верить тестам :
>   If === работает быстрей в 3раза 28 µs
>   if == также как и swich 77 µs